# Xampp - Mysql on USB not running - Changed ports, no errors displayed

Tags: mysql, usb, xampp

My MySQL once started runs for about 3 to 5 seconds before turning off. I've updated the my.ini file and changed the ports from `3306` to `3307` as I figured this was due to a problem with the fact that it was portable and the ports may have been used for something else.

Once I had made this change I closed Xampp and reopened it the status still shows:

`mysql State 0 Service 0 Start 0 Thread 0 Op 0 port 3306`

I've double checked my.ini and the changes have been made

I don't get any errors from Xampp displayed, mysql simply stops running without any information provided as to why.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: SO is not the place to ask for server/networking advice.

Comment: Sorry @Trent, looking on Google for an answer to this and most of the help I found came from SO so I naturally presumed that this would be a good place to start. Perhaps you could direct me on where a good place to ask is.